# xamarin android phoneword: no resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@mipmap/Icon')

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I am following the getting started guide for xamarin android but have encountered a problem.
I have finished all of the steps but when I go to build the app it gives me this error:
no resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@mipmap/Icon').
This is strange as I have all the Icon.png files in the different mipmap folders.

If anyone could help with this that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

nvm I figured out a workaround. The solution was to go into assemblyinfo.cs (which is under propterties) and add the following line:

[assembly: Application(Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]